# Intersection multiplicities of varieties expressed with curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, projective-varieties

Let $X,Y$ be different irreducible projective varieties in $\mathbb P^n$ (over an algebraically closed field). Let $Z$ be an irreducible component of $X\cap Y$. Then the *intersection multiplicity of $X$ and $Y$ along $Z$* is an (non-negative) integer defined in literatures such as Fulton's *Intersection theory*.

Let $m$ be the intersection multiplicity of $X$ and $Y$ along $Z$. Suppose also that $X$, $Y$ and $X\cap Y$ are non-trivial, $X$ and $Y$ are of dimensions $\ge 1$  and do not contain each other. Can we intuitively interpret the intersection multiplicity the following way:

> For every $P\in Z$ and every curve on $Y$ passing $P$ and not
> contained in $X$, the intersection multiplicity of the curve with $X$
> at $P$ is $\ge m$. Furthermore, there is such a curve such that
> equality holds.